# Aptana Studio 3.0.4: Errors and warnings stuck in "Problems" pane

Tags: aptana

I have 3 errors and 10 warnings that are "stuck", for lack of a better word, in the "Problems" pane. They're all related to JS/HTML and the project is a PyDev Django project.

There are no files open in Aptana. I've tried restarting multiple times. I've even gone into the preferences and turned off validation for both JS and HTML, yet they persist. Opening other files, such as a python file will update the "Problems" pane with any errors/warnings specific to that file, and removes the errors/warnings once that file is closed, as it should, but these always remain no matter what.

Any one have any idea how to clear this window pane (i.e. refresh it, etc.) so that it'll wake up and realize that it shouldn't be showing these errors/warnings any more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you have the auto-build turned off (so, turning it on and making a refresh in the file structure could make them go away in a new analysis).

If that doesn't work, try selecting the folder that contains the files with those errors, right clicking it and selecting: PyDev > remove error markers (the errors are not related to PyDev, but that action should remove any error markers, being from PyDev or not).

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you. My sanity is restored. PyDev > remove error markers worked beautifully.

Comment: PyDev---> remove error markers, worked for me, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to select the "stuck" problems in the Problems view, and delete them using the context (right-click) menu, or the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key.

Comment: There's no delete option in the context menu and the delete key does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when the 'build automatically' was enabled. However, I did not need to switch it off, I simply selected 'Project -> Clean' and all the errors/warnings disappeared.