# Aptana 3 and dojo 1.8.0 end tag problems

Tags: javascript, html, ide, dojo, aptana

I have just installed Aptana 3, created a new web project, and copied into the project the full source code for [dojo version 1.8.](http://dojotoolkit.org/download/)

After a full refresh and build, Aptana seems to find a high number of problems. Some of which are due to missing closing tags, but after a quick check, actually turn out to be the content of a table. There are other errors, some which are proper, I will look at these separately.

I cannot work out how to stop Aptana reporting these problems, can anyone help?

I have already read the following posts, but had no luck, the later gave me a temp fix, but the problems only came back after a project clean:

[dojo library syntax error in Aptana 3.1.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145273/dojo-library-syntax-error-in-aptana-3-1-3)

[Aptana Studio 3.0.4: Errors and warnings stuck in "Problems" pane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7250705/aptana-studio-3-0-4-errors-and-warnings-stuck-in-problems-pane)

Here is a snippet of code showing an example:

```
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Y >=
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input data-dojo-type="dijit.form.TextBox" data-dojo-attach-point="graphMinY" class="dojoxCalcGraphMinY" value="-10" />
                </td>

                <td>
Problem ==>         Y <=
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input data-dojo-type="dijit.form.TextBox" data-dojo-attach-point="graphMaxY" class="dojoxCalcGraphMaxY" value="10" />
                </td>
            </tr>
```

I have marker the line where just one of the problems is reported, but you can see that it is clearly just table content. Plus this is straight from dojo's site unaltered.

The actual problem copied from Aptana for this particular example is:

"<" missing '>' for end of tag  Grapher.html    /MSVis/libs/dojo-release-1.8.0-src/dojox/calc/templates line 31 HTML Syntax Problem

Thanks in advance for any help on this one.